# Trouble modifying the language option in selenium python bindings

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python in combination with selenium to scrape different app names from google play store and they all are coming through when I execute my script. However, the result are being converted into my native language that is not English.

***How can I modify the language option in selenium python bindings?***

My attempt (tried to change the language option but failed):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://play.google.com/store'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("accept-language=en-US")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get(link)
    for item in wait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.details a.title'))):
        print(item.text)
```

The output I'm having are in my native language which is not english.

Comment: What's showing on the page when you browse? Is it English or your native language? You may need to navigate to the English version of the page.

Comment: When I browse manually, I can see the content in english.

Comment: Do you have a Chrome profile where you have English set when you browse manually? When Chrome/Selenium runs, it runs with a clean profile which I'm assuming will display your native language. You may need to create a English profile (or use your current one) and specify that when your script starts.

Comment: I've tried with every suggestion and solution I've got so far in this post but none of them worked out except for the one provided by `Thomas G.`. However, that is merely a workaround.

Comment: @MITHU please check my updated answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55254431/5372079

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Not Working:**

I've tried the --lang, but it didn't worked for me:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
            OR
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
```

**Working Solution:**

After some research I found that to solve this, we have to use the experimental option intl.accept_languages:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

**Note: To use above, your website should need to support the same.**

> *There is one more way to achieve the same by translating your native language page to english:*

**Try using below code:**

```
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"your native language":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"True"}
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Comment: Finally some solution worked!! In order to make it work you need to replace this `{"enabled":"true"}` with this `{"enabled":"True"}`.

Comment: what should i do if this is not working for me?

Comment: @HarshVardhan Please provide more detail?

Answer (score 4):

I think your syntax for setting the language is off. Instead of

```
chrome_options.add_argument("accept-language=en-US")
```

Try

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

**Second Round**

Looks like english isn't available in `'intl.accept_languages'` yet.  But after a little more searching I found the following might work--give it a try?

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
```

**Third round**

Try using --lang=en-GB as Fenio suggests:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-GB")
```

Comment: your current implementation `en,en_US` still give me the page containing my native language. When I change this `en,en_US` to `ar` I can see the content in arabic language. That means you are on the right track? I tried with `en` but that didn't work either. How can i change it to english?

Comment: @MITHU Try `--lang=en-GB` instead of `en-US`

Answer (score 0):

All available switches for chromium (most should apply to chrome as well) can be found at:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#lang

I have not found **--accept-language** as one of them, but **--lang=locale** is one of them.

To be able to use it, the profile that will open the chrome session need to support it (being part of the supported language).

By default it won't. Only your native language will be part of it.
To add it, you can create new profiles

The below code will use one language per profile. Even if --lang=locale should work if your profile has it, it can be tricky as the Chrome UI implementation will use the one set by the main/first chrome window open. 
See @sarjoor answer for details explanation:
[How language work across multiple chrome windows](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/L_lzgshpWbY/RkVDiE_oDQAJ)

Now to create new profile:
[How to create a chrome profile](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/L_lzgshpWbY/RkVDiE_oDQAJ)

When your profile is created and you have started a session with it, go to:
chrome://settings/languages

Add your desired languages to it. Move the language on top of the list.

Then we need to specify the two profile switches:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=profileDirectory')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory="yourProfileName))
```

Your profile directory and Name can be found by going to: **chrome://version**

On macOS it is located at: 
*Profile Path   /Users/auto/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1*

```
profile_map = {
    'en': 'Default',
    'fr': 'Profile 1',
    'de': 'Profile 2'
}
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/auto/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format(profile_map['de']))
```

You might want to add the --lang switch but if the desired language for the profile is the default one it should work without it.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang='de'")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get(link)
    for item in wait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.details a.title'))):
        print(item.text)
```