# need translate webpage into English using python automation (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to translate webpage to English using python but not able to convert. can  anyone please help me

```
options.add_argument("−−lang=es")

# # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I added the options but not working

Comment: Does this answer to your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150118/trouble-modifying-the-language-option-in-selenium-python-bindings[

Comment: `options.add_argument("−−lang=es")` should be `options.add_argument("−−lang=en")` if you want to translate to English.

Comment: @Akzy `es` stands for _**espanol**_ i.e. _Spanish_

Comment: yes used that but not converting into english

Comment: Try using `options.add_argument("−−lang=en-US")` or `options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})`